# toBeCloseTo equivalent for recursive equality test in Jest

Tags: javascript, object, testing, numbers, jestjs

I have two objects and I want to test a recursive equality using Jest. This is pretty simple:

```
test('should be recursively equal', () => {
  const test = { x: 0, y: 0 }
  const expected = { x: 0, y: 0 }

  expect(test).toEqual(expected)
})
```

But there is a problem in some cases; as you know, JavaScript is pretty bad to compute float numbers, so sometimes the test becomes the following:

```
test('should be recursively equal', () => {
  const test = { x: 0.00000000001, y: 0 }
  const expected = { x: 0, y: 0 }

  expect(test).toEqual(expected)
})
```

And it does not work anymore. Jest provides the `toBeCloseTo` test, which takes a number and a precision as parameters, but I would like to know if there is an equivalent for recursive equalities (something like `toEqualCloseTo`).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I ended up with the following solution:

```
expect.extend({
  toEqualCloseTo(received, expected, precision = 3) {
    const { getType } = this.utils

    function round(obj) {
      switch (getType(obj)) {
      case 'array':
        return obj.map(round)

      case 'object':
        return Object.keys(obj).reduce((acc, key) => {
          acc[key] = round(obj[key])
          return acc
        }, {})

      case 'number':
        return +obj.toFixed(precision)

      default:
        return obj
      }
    }

    expect(round(received)).toEqual(expected)

    return { pass: true }
  },
})
```

Comment: I tweaked a couple of things for my code: `const { getType } = this.utils` to `const getType = type => typeof type;` and `expect(round(received)).toEqual(expected)` to `expect(round(received)).toEqual(round(expected))`

Comment: Using Jest 26, this code no longer works (`getType` is no longer exposed on `this.utils`). As @AJarofClay mentioned, it's easy to define your own, however we also must account for arrays (because `typeof anArray === 'object'`). A better definition is `const getType = x => Array.isArray(x) ? 'array' : typeof x;`